# Intel wireless network card cannot be properly initialized

Tags: wifi, intel, openwrt

I want to enable wireless on my openwrt but it doesn't work.
Besides, the wireless could be enabled through `iw phy phy0 add interface`command manually.

So, it seems there's something wrong in my kernel settings, but I don't know where it is.

```
Wed Sep  6 07:10:38 2023 user.notice mac80211: Failed command: iw phy phy0 set antenna 0xffffffff 0xffffffff
Wed Sep  6 07:10:38 2023 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (2855): command failed: Not supported (-95)
Wed Sep  6 07:10:38 2023 user.notice mac80211: Failed command: iw phy phy0 set distance 0
Wed Sep  6 07:10:38 2023 daemon.notice procd: /etc/rc.d/S45nfs: exportfs: could not open /var/lib/nfs/.etab.lock for locking: errno 2 (No such file or directory)
Wed Sep  6 07:10:38 2023 daemon.notice procd: /etc/rc.d/S45nfs: exportfs: could not open /var/lib/nfs/.etab.lock for locking: errno 2 (No such file or directory)
Wed Sep  6 07:10:38 2023 daemon.notice procd: /etc/rc.d/S45nfs: exportfs: can't lock /var/lib/nfs/etab for writing
Wed Sep  6 07:10:38 2023 daemon.notice procd: /etc/rc.d/S50autoreboot: Command failed: Not found
Wed Sep  6 07:10:38 2023 cron.info crond[2955]: crond (busybox 1.30.0) started, log level 5
Wed Sep  6 07:10:38 2023 daemon.notice procd: /etc/rc.d/S50autoreboot: Auto REBOOT has started.
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 kern.err kernel: [   21.191764] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 kern.info kernel: [   21.198467] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 kern.info kernel: [   21.205423] br-lan: port 2(wlan0) entered blocking state
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 kern.info kernel: [   21.211158] br-lan: port 2(wlan0) entered disabled state
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 kern.info kernel: [   21.216934] device wlan0 entered promiscuous mode
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 kern.info kernel: [   21.222026] br-lan: port 2(wlan0) entered blocking state
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 kern.info kernel: [   21.227769] br-lan: port 2(wlan0) entered forwarding state
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 kern.info kernel: [   21.233837] br-lan: port 2(wlan0) entered disabled state
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 daemon.err hostapd: Driver does not support configured VHT capability [VHT_CAP_SHORT_GI_80]
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 daemon.notice hostapd: wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 daemon.notice hostapd: wlan0: AP-DISABLED
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 daemon.err hostapd: wlan0: Unable to setup interface.
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 daemon.notice hostapd: wlan0: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 daemon.notice hostapd: wlan0: AP-DISABLED
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 daemon.notice hostapd: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 daemon.err hostapd: hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 daemon.notice hostapd: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 kern.info kernel: [   21.299316] device wlan0 left promiscuous mode
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 kern.info kernel: [   21.304140] br-lan: port 2(wlan0) entered disabled state
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (2855): cat: can't open '/var/run/wifi-phy0.pid': No such file or directory
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (2855): WARNING (wireless_add_process): executable path /usr/sbin/wpad does not match process  path (/proc/exe)
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (2855): Command failed: Invalid argument
Wed Sep  6 07:10:39 2023 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (2855): Device setup failed: HOSTAPD_START_FAILED
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hostapd: Driver does not support configured VHT capability [VHT_CAP_SHORT_GI_80]
```

Apparently your `hostapd.conf` includes something like

```
vht_capab=[SHORT-GI-80]
```

but this WiFi card seems to be unable to support that. Remove the `[SHORT-GI-80]` element from the `vht_capab=` line, and try again.